# Powershell - Delete / remove all site collection under a spesific managed path

Tags: powershell, site-collection, delete, managed-path

I've created a managed path for my team sites - called "workspaces". All team sites Have been created under the same managed path.

```
 ex: 
 http://awesome.com/workspaces/teamsite1
 http://awesome.com/workspaces/teamsite2
```

How can I list all team sites under a managed path?

What I want is to delete all site collection under a specific managed path. (remove site collection and DB-entry)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To list them, this actually gives you all sites under the path though:

```
Get-SPSite "http://awesome.com/workspaces*" -Limit ALL
```

To delete you should be able to use

```
Get-SPSite "http://awesome.com/workspaces*" -Limit ALL | Remove-SPSite -Confirm:$false
```

You can use

```
Remove-SPContentDatabase -Identity {GUID}
```

to remove a content database

Comment: ty, do this code delete the team-site-db?

Comment: No it does not, it just removes the site collections from the database.

Comment: Updated with how you can remove a content database if needed

Answer (score 0):

You can delete site collection using powershell by using following command

```
$tmpRoot = Get-SPWebApplication -Identity http://SP:2000
$tmpRootColl=$tmpRoot.Sites
#Enumerate through each site collection
for ($index=$tmpRootColl.Count-1 ; $index-ge 0 ; $index–-)
{
  Remove-SPSite -Identity $tmpRootColl.Item($index) -GradualDelete -Confirm:$false
}
Get-SPDeletedSite | Remove-SPDeletedSite
```

Where **$tmpRoot** is Web Application and **$tmpRootColl** is collection of sites under web application

Find full code with explanation from this blog [CodePlayAndLearn](https://codeplayandlearn.wordpress.com/2016/04/20/delete-site-collection-using-powershell/)